# c++ string operation for both iOS and Android platform

Tags: c++, ios, string

I am porting a game from objC (ios) to C++. Please advise me if there is any cross-platform C++ library to get equivalent of following objC string operation.

stringByAppendingPathComponent

stringByDeletingLastPathComponent

lastPathComponent

stringByDeletingPathExtension

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_path) which offers some pathing specific behavior. You could also build your own methods fairly easily using methods from `std::string`. The first answer [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1962/) has some examples of that (although their not doing exactly what you want, but it will give you a general idea).

Comment: Thanks for a prompt help. Can you please confirm if we Boost library could be used for both iOS and Android platform.